# I have a Blazor Server app. In my razor page I cannot align my selectbox in a table row , vertically in the middle. What could be the problem?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

I have tried to use vertical-align:middle both in css and in the select object, but still the select box is aligned to the bottom of the table row.

CSS file

```
.td_button_bar {
background-color: #eaf2f8;
border: none;
left:10px;
margin-left:10px;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.tr_button_bar {
max-height: 60px;
margin-top: 0px;
top: 0px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Razor code

```
<table class="page_header">
<tr>
    <td class="page_header">&emsp;&#9432;Info:&emsp; @TagService.Message_CNC_Status</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr_button_bar">
    <td class="td_button_bar" align="left" >
        
        <button class="button_1" disabled="@TagService.IsDisabled_Read_Drive_Monitor" @onclick="Read_Drive_Monitor"><img class="button_image" src="images/play.svg"><br>Start</button>
        <button class="button_1" disabled="@TagService.IsDisabled_Stop_Drive_Monitor" @onclick="Stop_Drive_Monitor"><img class="button_image" src="images/stop.svg"><br>Stop</button>
        <select style="width:150px; height:30px ;vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block" value="@TagService.Drive_Monitor_selected_AX_No" class="Dep" disabled="@TagService.IsDisabled_Drive_Monitor_selected_AX" @onchange="func_AX_select" @onclick="Read_NC_AX_List_MD10000">
            <option value="-1">--Select AX--</option>
            @for (int j = 0; j < 31; j++)

            {
                var jj = j;
                var kk = j + 1;
                if (Deltalogic.NC_AX_List_MD10000[j] == "")
                {
                    break;
                }
                <option value=@kk>@Deltalogic.NC_AX_List_MD10000[j]</option>
            }

        </select>
    </td>
  
</tr>
```

Comment: Any reason why you are specifying a height for the select element? It will adjust according to the content. Also, you only need to specify the vertical-inline: align in the td_button_bar class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using built-in Bootstrap classes: [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) and apply `align-self-center`

Here is a jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/maciekn/Lx40s7wk/

```
<table class="container">
    <tr>
        <td class="page_header">&emsp;&#9432;Info:&emsp; </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_button_bar">
        <td class="td_button_bar" align="left" >
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <button class="button_1" ><br>Start</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="button_1" ><br>Stop</button>
                </div>
                <div class="align-self-center">
                    <select style="width:150px; height:30px ;vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block">
                    <option value="-1">--Select AX--</option>
                    @for (int j = 0; j < 31; j++)

                    {
                        var jj = j;
                        var kk = j + 1;

                        <option value=@kk></option>
                    }
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```